# Multilingual email working fine for email subject but not working in Body PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, multilingual

I'm working on multilingual website ,and we've send email to user in preferred language.

Email subject is visible ok but in body It will display unreadable characters:

[image]

PHPMailer Code:

```
   $body = file_get_contents('mailtemplate/base_template.html');
   $body = str_replace('{sn}', $senderUser['user_firstname'], $body);
   $body = str_replace('{eb}', $msg, $body);
   $mail = new sendemail($this->config);
   $mail->SendEmail($this->logger, $this->config, $recUser['user_name'], 'Subject : ' . $senderUser['user_firstname'] . ' sent a message to you', $body, ''))
```

Comment: I don't see a whole lot of code here... But I'm assuming it's a character encoding issue. Make sure the email is sent as UTF-8.

Comment: @mike I've added my code

Comment: Try adding `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: @mike thanks its working :)

Comment: Thanks Mike & Govind Samrow.